# interface freeze when trying to update datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using below code to copy files and set status column at `datagridview` to inform user that connection is up but when I press the button to execute is
method the interface freeze...

I have searched a lot i know that using `task.run();` is not possible since it is not included in `.not 4` it a new feature of `.net 4.5` i also know that `Task.Factory.StartNew();`  can be used instead of using task.run() but it has a lot of risk as implicit thread and i know that using explicit threading is also good choose a

i want a little help to go on with my project and keep learning instead of getting stacked at that boring point

```
public void PatchUpdates()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
        {
            string OfficeIPAddress = OfficeListRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
            {
                string SoruceFileNamePath = FileListRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                string DestinationFileNamePath = @"\\" + OfficeIPAddress + @"\usb1_1\test\" + Path.GetFileName(SoruceFileNamePath);

                //check if connection to remote server is available
                var vResult = CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress);

                if (vResult == 1)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[4, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "Connected";
                    File.Copy(SoruceFileNamePath, DestinationFileNamePath, true); //copy files...
                }
                else if (vResult == 0)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[4, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "disconnected";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

check office code below

```
    public int CheckOffice(string _ipAddress)
    {
        int timeout = 120;
        string data = "PingTestData";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        Ping PingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

        options.DontFragment = true;

        PingReply reply = PingSender.Send(_ipAddress, timeout, buffer, options);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

below how I have tried to make thread but that wont solve my problem

```
public void PatchUpdates()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
        {
            string OfficeIPAddress = OfficeListRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
            {
                string SoruceFileNamePath = FileListRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                string DestinationFileNamePath = @"\\" + OfficeIPAddress + @"\usb1_1\test\" + Path.GetFileName(SoruceFileNamePath);


                Thread foregroundthread = new Thread(() => CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress));

                foregroundthread.Start();

                //check if connection to remote server is available
                if (CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress) == 1)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[3, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "Connected";
                    //file.copy(sorucefilenamepath, destinationfilenamepath, true); //copy files...
                }
                else if (CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress) == 0)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[3, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "disconnected";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I have also tried this but as i said thask.run is not available at dot net 4

```
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var result = CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress);

            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[4, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "Connected";
                    //file.copy(sorucefilenamepath, destinationfilenamepath, true); //copy files...
                }
                else if (result == 0)
                {
                    DGV_OfficeList[4, DGV_OfficeList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = "disconnected";
                }
            }));
        }
    );
```

**--------------------------------------------------------- Update ---------------------------------------------------------**

```
    public void PatchUpdates()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
            {
                string OfficeIPAddress = OfficeListRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                int RowNum = OfficeListRow.Index;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
                {
                    string SoruceFileNamePath = FileListRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    //string DestinationFileNamePath = @"\\" + OfficeIPAddress + @"\usb1_1\test\" + Path.GetFileName(SoruceFileNamePath);
                    string DestinationFileNamePath = @"F:\test\" + Path.GetFileName(SoruceFileNamePath); //TestPurpose

                    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        int vResult = CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress);
                        UpdateUI(vResult, RowNum, SoruceFileNamePath, DestinationFileNamePath, OfficeIPAddress);
                    }));
                    t2.Start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

The UpdateUI method to update UI...

```
    public void UpdateUI(int vResult, int RowNum, string SoruceFileNamePath, string DestinationFileNamePath,string OfficeIPAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

            if ((DateTime.Now - PreviousTime).Milliseconds <= 10)
                return;

            SynchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
                    {
                        if (vResult == 1)
                        {
                            DGV_OfficeList[4, RowNum].Value = "Connected";
                            //File.Copy(SoruceFileNamePath, DestinationFileNamePath, true);
                            //MessageBox.Show("Pingable " + OfficeIPAddress); //TestPurpose
                        }
                        else if (vResult == 0)
                        {
                            DGV_OfficeList[4, RowNum].Value = "Disconnected";
                            //MessageBox.Show("Not reachable"); //TestPurpose
                        }
                    }), vResult);

            PreviousTime = timeNow;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Debug it and see which line is problematic. Might be `CheckOffice()`.

Comment: @Mat I ipdate my post and post the CheckOffice() code I dont think 
it is the problem please please help me I want to know

Comment: google "async await" or "multithreading"

Comment: There are plenty of questions about "UI freeze". Your post does not demonstrate all the research you've done prior asking the question. This will likely bring downvotes. Note that asking "don't downvote" does not add any useful information to the post and potentially just increase number of downvotes (so I've edited that out).

Comment: @Mat The UI will be frozen from the instant the operation starts until the instant that it finishes.  And that will be true for any synchronous operation.  There isn't a point part way through where the UI becomes frozen.

Comment: Right ! Then may I suggest simply editing the question since the code isn't relevant ? (Other than the first line which shows it's not `async`)

Comment: @Mat Well it's relevant to fixing the problem...just not diagnosing it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know but I have searched a lot i know that using task.run(); is not possible since it is not included in .not 4 it a new feature of .net 4.5 i also know that Task.Factory.StartNew() can be used instead of using task.run()  but it has a lot of risk as implicit thread and i know that using explicit threading is also good choose all that  demonstrate all the research i have done before posting here my friend but my problem that i have not used them before and i want a little help to go on with my project and keep learning instead of getting stacked at that silly boring point!!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov and here is what I have tried before and posted and i was not able to move on that point... now can you help me please my friend ?

Comment: I'd recommend to re-read this sentence from my comment - "Your post *does not demonstrate* all the research" - important part made italic for ease of finding.

Comment: @Mat yes its NOT async thing

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay thanks it is noted and ill keep trying...

Comment: `Thread foregroundthread = new Thread(() => CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress));` won't change anything if you still call `CheckOffice(OfficeIPAddress) == 1` in the current thread. Implying `CheckOffice` takes a lot of time because of the ping, you'd need to put all code that requires its return value Inside `foregroundthread`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: There is nothing wrong with your code. The design is not good.

**Long Answer**

Have you heard someone say "I can only do one thing at a time!" Well that is what is going on here. Your windows forms application's code is being executed by 1 thread and that thread can only do one thing at a time. When it is pinging, it waits for the reply. If the reply is successful it then copies a file. Since you have a loop it keeps doing this until it has completed all rows.

While it is doing that, you are probably clicking other things in the UI, but your thread "can only do 1 thing at a time". It is busy doing the stuff in the loop. Therefore, when you are clicking, you just have to wait.

**So how do I fix it so the UI does not freeze?**

In plain English, you need to do this. Imagine you are a thread:

I am the UI thread and my ultimate goal is to keep the UI responsive. I do not want the UI to freeze. Therefore, if I need to do anything except UI work, I am going to ask someone else to do it. While that someone else is doing other work, I will be free to do UI work.

That someone else is another thread. Here is an example, read my comments in the code and apply it to your application. If you want to run this code, create a form `Form1` with a label named `label1` and two buttons. Assign `ButtonClickHandlerAsync` to one button's click handler and  `Stop_Click` to the other button.

The whole action starts when you click the button which executes `ButtonClickHandlerAsync`. While it is doing work, you can click the other button and it will show a message box and stay responsive. By the way I have copied this code from [here](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/) but I added my own comments inside the code so you know what is going on.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

   // We need this because this will allow us to interact with UI controls. UI controls can only be accessed by the thread that 
   // created the UI control. In this case it is the thread which started the application so the main thread.
   private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
   private DateTime previousTime = DateTime.Now;

   public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
   }

   private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      // I am the UI thread. I can do this because T2 is helping me do the loop.
      MessageBox.Show( "I am doing other things." );
   }

   private async void ButtonClickHandlerAsync(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      button1.Enabled = false;
      var count = 0;

      // I am the UI thread. I have other things to do. So please run this loop by using a thread from the thread pool.
      // When you are done running the loop let me know (This is what the await does)
      // I am the UI thread so I am going to return back from right here
      // to the point where ButtonClickHandlerAsync was called from. (it was called by a click, so when it returns it will have nothing
      // to do. Therefore, it will be ready to react to another UI job such as another click or update the UI etc.
      await Task.Run( () =>
      {
         // I am a thread from the thread pool. My name is T2. I am helping the UI thread so the UI thread can do other things.
         for( var i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++ ) {
            UpdateUI( i );
            count = i;
         }
      } );


      // I am the UI thread. Ok looks like the loop is done. So I will do the following 2 lines of work
      label1.Text = @"Counter " + count;
      button1.Enabled = true;
   }

   public void UpdateUI(int value) {

      // I am T2. I am helping the UI thread.
      var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

      if( ( DateTime.Now - previousTime ).Milliseconds <= 50 )
         return;

      // I do not have access to the UI controls since I did not create them. So I am just going to ask the synchronizationContext
      // to do this for me by giving it a SendOrPostCallback
      synchronizationContext.Post( new SendOrPostCallback( o =>
      {
         // I am the UI thread. I will do this.
         label1.Text = @"Counter " + ( int ) o;
      } ), value );

      // I am T2. I will do this and then return and do more work.
      previousTime = timeNow;
   }
```

**How can you fix your code?**

You can do `CheckOffice` and copying the files using a thread from the threadpool. That thread can use the `synchronizationContext` to if it needs to interact with the UI. The main UI thread can stay free to do other things while the thread from the thread pool is checking the office and copying a file which could take a long time, especially, if the file is big.

**"I am the UI thread. I have no time to wait for a ping reply." 
"I am the UI thread. I have no time to copy a file from one location to another location which can take seconds or minutes. My job is to keep the UI responsive."**

**EDIT**

I wrote the above answer before the OP wrote the restriction of .NET 4. But I am pretty sure they have created a NuGet package for this. See [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

If you cannot use `async` and `await`, the same concepts above apply to threading.

```
Thread t2 = new Thread( new ThreadStart(() =>
{
   for( var i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++ ) {
      UpdateUI( i );
      count = i;
   }
} ) );
t2.Start();
```

Comment: thanks  for your very very useful explanation but one think and I am sorry to say that as I said at my original post that  Task.Run() is not available at dot net v4 its new feature of dot net v4.5 and using Task.Factory.StartNew(); has a risk as i found when I searched about it so that example partially not applicable am I right ?

Comment: @Sam see my edit. It is the same idea to be honest with you.

Comment: sorry for the late response to you my friend I was spending all the time trying to understand the case and build it and I really appreciate your help.. please I had update my post the new code... please if you wish to take a look and advise me if there is anything wrong... Thank you..

Comment: Don't call updateui if result is 1. There is no ui to update. If result is 1 you want to copy the file. Do that on the thread or the ui will freeze again until the copy is completed

Comment: your suggested way works like charm and the interface not freezing even if i have update the UI in both cases when the vResult is 1 or vResult is 0, but i am looking now for the strange think that not all rows at column status ascended to connected or disconnected according the vResult value... its look like i have to press the button again to get that result for the rest of rows ... as u can see it at screen shot two it's update 5 row only

Comment: its looks like the interface update once and not keep looking for any changes because the ping method waits for 120 to get reply... i do not if its repet the ping for three times and it happen when i ping ip using cmd  "ping 127.0.0.10"

Comment: Sam sorry i just saw this. Perhaps create another question with the new issue and someone can help you?