# C# Winform, Updating GUI elements without interrupting user

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, backgroundworker

I've created a program that updates textBox1 based on the value of numericUpDown1.  It does so via a background worker that Invokes to the GUI thread to do the update.  Changing the value of the numericUpDown by trying to change the text is impossible, it is constantly being interrupted by the textbox update, however using the up and down arrows works fine.  Is there a way to update the textbox without interrupting a user trying to modify the value of the numericUpDown?  I've attached a simple and crude example of what I'm doing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace t
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int value = 0;
            while (bw.CancellationPending == false)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    value = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                    textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
                });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [interface freeze when trying to update datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271185/interface-freeze-when-trying-to-update-datagridview)

Comment: Why cant you update the textbox from the valuechanged event?  Besides which you are not supposed to fiddle with the UI from the worker thread

Comment: Why do you have a thread involved at all? It's the totally wrong way to approach this issue. The controls have events that are fired that are to be used for this sort of thing - threads are not supposed to be used to affect the UI.

Comment: I very much understand what you are all saying about using a different approach (especially the event handler).  In reality I have program that uses a thread to pull data from instruments (time consuming) and I want to update various GUI elements to show the collected data.  My example code is just my attempt to distill the problem I'm facing with my thread updating the GUI while a user tries to manipulate a GUI element.