# How to implement async INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class with properties that are bound to my view. To keep my view up-to-date, I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the event everytime some property changes.

Now I got some heavy functions that freeze my application. I want to put them into a background task.

First: here my current approach

(e.g. on button click)

```
private async void HeavyFunc()
{
    foreach (var stuff)
    {
        count += await Task.Run(() => stuff.Fetch());
    }

    if (count == 0)
        //...
}
```

stuff class

```
public async Task<int> Fetch()
{
    //network stuff

    RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
}

public async void RaisePropertyChanged(string pChangedProperty)
{
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pChangedProperty);
        }
    );
}
```

The code above gives an exception ("DependencySource" must be created in the same thread like "DependencyObject").

AFAIK, you generally need to create a new thread and run it (while awaiting it). ´await Task.Run(...);´ should do this job.

Since the PropertyChanged event directly influences the UI, calling it in the UI thread seems to be a good decision. This is why I call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

What I don't understand: the exception above is caused when different threads are responsible for the data. But I explicitely calling the event on my UI-thread and the object should be created by the UI-thread too. So why do I get an exception?

My main question is: How do I implement the events for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface generally to avoid or handle most of the async programming problems like above? What should be considered while constructing the functions?

Comment: You are raising the propertychanged event on the thread so it will not be able to access ui elements if it never created them.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271185/interface-freeze-when-trying-to-update-datagridview/41272238#41272238) to really understand which code is executed by the ui thread vs another thread

Comment: Is the property itself a DepedencyObject like a bitmap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now I got some heavy functions that freeze my application.

If you're really doing asynchronous "network stuff", then it shouldn't be freezing the app.

> My main question is: How do I implement the events for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface generally to avoid or handle most of the async programming problems like above?

The approach that I prefer is to **not** handle this in the event raising code. Instead, structure the *rest* of your code so that it respects the UI layer.

In other words, divide your "service" (or "business logic") code from your "UI" code so that it works like this:

```
// In StuffService class:
public async Task<Result> FetchAsync()
{
  //network stuff
  return result;
}

// In StuffViewModel class:
public async void ButtonClicked()
{
  foreach (var stuff)
  {
    var result = await Task.Run(() => _stuffService.FetchAsync());
    MyProperty = result.MyProperty;
    count += result.Count;
  }

  if (count == 0)
    //...
}

public Property MyProperty
{
  get { return _myProperty; }
  set
  {
    _myProperty = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged();
  }
}
private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string pChangedProperty = null)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pChangedProperty));
}
```

This way, there's no manual thread jumping, all properties have the standard ViewModel implementation, the code is simpler and more maintainable, etc.

I did leave in the call to `Task.Run`, although this *should* be superfluous if your network calls are truly asynchronous.